# Ubuntu freeze after moving window to the side

Tags: unity, 13.10, freeze

When I move a window to the left or right side, it should automatically resize itself (I don't know how this function is called, but it is also present on windows 7). My problem is, that Ubuntu freeze (all unity) during this process, and I can't do anything, only force restart, or switch to another tty.

What can I do?

Comment: Need information about your hardware here. Can you go to console by CTRL-ALT-F1? Can you restart X by CTRL-ALT-Backspace?

Comment: Hardware is Lenovo e530, and yes, I can go to console using CTRL-ALT-F1, and I am not sure, but I cannot restart x.

Comment: At least it says, that the system is not totally locking up.

Comment: Antything visible with dmesg?

Comment: Nothing special. I resolve with a strange way. I disable this function. And reenable it. And it started to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable that feature :

Install Unity Tweak Tool, a program that will help you configure Unity :

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Open it and go to *Windows Snapping*, and switch it off.

You will still be able to snap your windows using `<Ctrl> + <Super> + <Left>/<Right>/<Up>/<Down>`

Note : the `<Super>` key is also called `<Windows>`

Comment: I think his problem is a stability issue.

Comment: I disable this function, and reenable it, using unity tweak tool. And it looks that it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Press the Windows key + A will unfreeze expanded desktops.